# Setting menu trail of subpage of a node

Tags: 7, routes

I'm trying to have a subpage for a special content type. Everything is working fine, also the breadcrumb is working now.

Only the active menu trail isn't showing up and I really don't know how to hack into the right process. Are there any special functions helping me with this problem?

I tried `menu_set_active_trail()`, but having problems with nodes placed in a menu by the user where I cannot get the previous menu trail for the node itself.

I hope you can help.
Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you need is [menu_tree_set_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_tree_set_path/7).  It will be released with Drupal 7.9.

If you can't wait, the workaround is to use this code in hook_init:

```
<?php
$item = menu_get_item();
$item['href'] = '<the href of an existing menu link>';
menu_set_item(NULL, $item);
?>
```